# People press shift while on my tab, but release it on another. How to prevent Ctrl+Shift+Tab from breaking my "shift_pressed" variable?

Tags: javascript, browser

I am working on a to-do list browser application (written in JavaScript, HTML and CSS, no jQuery), and I wanted to add custom behaviour for *tab* and *shift + tab*, because those should be indentation rather than navigation. Since there is no way to catch a key combination directly, I created a `shift_pressed` variable that detects when *shift* is pressed:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Shift') {
        shift_pressed = false;
    }
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Shift') {
        shift_pressed = true;
    } else if (event.key === "Tab") {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (shift_pressed) {
            minus_indent();
        } else {
            plus_indent();
        }
    }
});
```

This works great, as long as the user stays on my tab. However, when someone uses *control+shift+tab* to move to the previous tab in their browser, they press *shift* on my tab, causing the `shift_pressed` variable to become `true`. Then, they release it on another tab, causing `shift_pressed` to stay `true`, even if they return. They then need to press and release *shift* again to fix it.

I decided, if the issue is *control+shift+tab*, let's just catch control as well. So I did this:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.key === "Control") {
        ctrl = false;
    }
```

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.key === 'Shift') {
        if (!ctrl) {
            shift_pressed = true;
        }
    } else if (event.key === "Control") {
        ctrl = true;
    }
```

This works, as long as people navigate tabs **only** using *control+tab* or *control+shift+tab*.
When they navigate away, *control* must be pressed, and when they navigate back, *control* must be released on my tab, so this works.

The problem is, if someone tabs away using *control+shift+tab*, then `shift_pressed` may stay `false`, but `ctrl` becomes `true`. And if they then navigate back not with *control+tab* (which would set `ctrl` back to `false`) but by clicking on the tab in their browser, `ctrl` stays `true`. This then means that *shift* is completely blocked from usage until they press and release *control* again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure to reset your booleans when switching tabs, to do so you can use the following:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilityChange", () => {
  if (document.visibilityState === "hidden") {
    shift_pressed = false;
    ctrl = false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Doing this but for window.addEventListener('focus') fixed it!
I thought this might cause issues because what if someone presses shift while away and then clicks on the tab, but apparently in that case an onkeydown is activated when you enter the tab.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to roll your own. You can just check the existing `shiftKey` modifier (a `ctrlKey` modified also exists).

```js
   if (event.key === "Tab") {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.shiftKey) {
            minus_indent();
        } else {
            plus_indent();
        }
    }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/shiftKey
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey